# CollapsingToolbarLayout not working(collapsing)when scrolled

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, androiddesignsupport, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to create a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and below it a listview, when the listview is scrolled the Toolbar should collapse, but its not working when scrolled the Toolbar is not collapsing.

Used this tutorial: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015_05_01_archive.html

Note: The FrameLayout contains the listview

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="192dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbara"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

The framelayout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ranjithnair02.com.supporttest.BlankFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/rcyv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="5dp"
        app:rippleColor="@color/wallet_highlighted_text_holo_light" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Try replacing the root `LinearLayout` with `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should use [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) instead of ListView

Note:
don't forget to update RecyclerView in Gradle file.

```
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
```

Comment: Note, you can wrap any container within a `NestedScrollView` from the `Support Design Library` and it will work too. So you could wrap the `ListView` within the `NestedSrollView`

Comment: You should not put Listview inside any ScrollView

Comment: Wrapping the ListView Inside a nested ScrollViewWon't work

Comment: If you use ` myRecycleForPrescription.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` For Recycle View  Then app behavior will not work

Answer (score 7):

For my case : **I dint give height to my `Toolbar`** .

It was `wrap_content`. If thats the case then try to fix the height of the `Toolbar` using :-

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me! As a matter of fact, if no specific height is set on the Toolbar, CollapsingToolbarLayout has no clue on the collapsed height

Comment: This is what helped me for my combination with fragments! Even though it's contrary to what's in the Material3 docs

Answer (score 6):

I did an example by using RecyclerView instead. The source code could be found here:
https://github.com/jiahaoliuliu/MaterialDesignSample/tree/collapsingToolbars

There are a couple of things that you should take into account and the post does not says.

1. Use CoordinatorLayout as the main layout
2. Use a theme without ActionBar and set the toolbar as actionBar instead. You can do it by creating a special theme for the activity like this:

   ```
   <!-- Indigo without actionbar when toolbar is used -->
   <style name="IndigoWithoutActionBar" parent="Indigo">
       <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
       <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   </style>
   ```

   And in the AndroidManifest.xml file, do the follow:

   ```
   <activity
       android:name=".CollapsingToolbarActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/IndigoWithoutActionBar"
       >
   </activity>
   ```

   Once this is done, set it on the Java code:

   ```
   // Actionbar
   final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   ```

Here is a functional xml code that I use.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/simpleRecyclerView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If this is not enough for you, you can follow the code of Chris Banes here:
https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: I am able to get it work with `RecyclerView`. My problem is I want to use `FrameLayout`.

Comment: @Psypher: You should put your `FrameLayout` inside a `NestedScrollView`

Answer (score 3):

You need to add two things to the list view and it will work

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"

app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

My working XML code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context="com.example.pr20020897.samplapp.DisplayAllDataActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="72dp"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/db"
                android:contentDescription="image" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
                app:contentInsetStart="72dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ListView
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#FF0000"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp">
    </ListView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Hopefully help someone.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `RelativeLayout`. Try replacing the `FrameLayout` with the `ListView` and then the `FloatingButton`. All wrapped in a `CoordinatorLayout` of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Comment: Also you should wrap all in CoordinationLayout