# Avoid ViewPager going under Toolbar

Tags: android, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

Based on
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34896401/4543112) answer I tried to make a solution for my Use Case. Instead of using a Collapsing toolbar I'm using a regular one but with a `TabLayout`. However, for the `TabLayout` I need to use a `ViewPager` and I have no idea where to place it in order to avoid trouble with the `FrameLayout`. ViewPager was in my Host Fragment and when its layout replaced the FrameLayout, the content went below the Toolbar and TabLayout for some reason...

I tried putting it below that line

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

in `the app_bar_main.xml` but it messed up my UI.

The real question is, if I need a FrameLayout for my fragments and I need a ViewPager for my TabLayout, how do I implement a solution?

You can see that I moved the view a bit so that the Toolbar hides. This way it's visible the ViewPager takes up space even below the Toolbar (when it's visible)

[image: Screenshot]

Current attempt - **appbar_content** (Toolbar is just a Toolbar in separate layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/teal"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/purple800"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/tabicons"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tealfifty"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabCapsFalse"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/iron" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<include layout="@layout/content_main" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main** (removed NestedScrollView as it screwed up everything, put my whole fragment view like in a small frame(maybe 50x50 size) in the middle of the screen)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/content_main_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

My **DrawerLayout**:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<include
    layout="@layout/appbar_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/tealfifty"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_view_items" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of struggling, I found that putting a NestedScrollView inside my FrameLayout and assigning a layout_behaviour to my FrameLayout made the Scroll View inherit it and now it all works like a charm!

**This is my DrawerLayout**:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<include
    layout="@layout/appbar_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/tealfifty"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_view_items" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**appbar_content.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/teal"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/purple800"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/tabicons"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tealfifty"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabCapsFalse"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/iron" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/content_main_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:showIn="@layout/appbar_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/addico"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/content_main_frame"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
```

Comment: I had the same issue with ViewPager. Adding the layout_behaviour attribute to ViewPager, solved the issue..

Comment: Glad you fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

Put your tab layout and view pager inside a linear layout with orientation vertical. So your linear layout will be the child of Coordinator layout. THis will make sure your view pager starts below tablayout.

Comment: My TabLayout is a part of an AppBarLayout so that it moves along with the Toolbar when it collapses. My ViewPager is not even in the same layout. TabLayout and Toolbar are in a DrawerLayout so I don't think what you suggested can be implemented? Did you see the answer I said I followed as a solution?