# CollapsingToolbarLayout's collapsing is not working

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

here is my `activity_article_list.xml`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout        
    ...
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        ...
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyAppBarTheme">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            ...
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <include layout="@layout/activity_toolbar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        ...
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <com.malinskiy.superrecyclerview.SuperRecyclerView
            .../>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this is `activity_toolbar.xml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    ...
    android:id="@+id/list_toolbar"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/MyTheme">

    <RelativeLayout>

        <ImageButton
            ... />

        <ImageButton
            .../>

        <TextView
            ... />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

in style, MyTheme is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`,

and MyAppBarTheme is `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar`.

i saw many questions about collapsing toolbar.

I think my xml is similar to the content of a question or lecture.

i  think the point is `layout_scrollFlags`, `layout_collapseMode`, `layout_scrollFlags`.

however, toolbar didn't disappear according to the scroll.

it remains in place.

has MyAppBarTheme wrong parent?

or any wrong codes?

Edit : my full code in `activity_article_list.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/MyAppBarTheme">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/list_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:minHeight="0dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/MyTheme">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/boardName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.malinskiy.superrecyclerview.SuperRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/article_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/windowBackground"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Check This Stackoverflow Question it will might help you [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558139/collapsingtoolbarlayout-not-workingcollapsingwhen-scrolled)

Comment: @RohitChauhan ok i'll apply this first

Comment: i found solution. it simple. 
first, remove superrecyclerview. 
second, use recyclerview under swiperefreshlayout. 
third, remove recyclerView.setNestedScrollEnabled(false). after do this, it works fine. i hope anyone can solve this problem with this comment.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is a reference to my code where is implemented collapsing toolbar
>   ... try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/layout_toolbar"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#0000"
                >

                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:contentScrim="#0000"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll">

                    <include layout="@layout/home_menu_items"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/hot_deals_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:layout_weight=".3"
                        android:id="@+id/pdt_info_tv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="Hot Deals"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:gravity="start|center"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/black_dark"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/show_More"
                        android:layout_weight=".7"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="Show More"
                        android:gravity="right|center"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black_moderate"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                    android:scrollbars="none" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: For reference, my xml looks like this: 
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <CoordinatorLayout>
            <AppBarLayout>
                <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
                    <Toolbar/>
                </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            </AppBarLayout>
            <RecyclerView/>
        </CoordinatorLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</CoordinatorLayout>

it still same. :(